# Automated Script for photos & printing - Direction / Comments welcome

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This is what i'm hoping to achieve, i'm no expert, so am i wasting my time?

1. Photo Comes in from camera - Using a wifi SD, Creates copy to folder instantly (using a .bat)
2. Batch file runs, and checks periodically files, 
   once there are 4 files total, it moves the files to a unique
   folder, say folder 1, 2, 3 etc.

3.Vb script then Runs the folder through Irfan, to create a 
'Panorama' Images.

4.Panorama Image is then Automatically Printed using .Bat file

---

1.This could be Inclusive of another operation

2. Can this be included below?
3. This is the script that i'm using for, this runs great however i have to manually drag folder with 3 image onto the *.vbs:

   ```
   dim shell, fso
   Dim f, folderlist, item, File(4), process, panout, Irfanview, Appcall
   Dim mask, test, dot, extn, count
   set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   set shell = createObject("WScript.shell")

   'Defaults
   Irfanview = "C:\Program files\Irfanview\i_view64.exe"  'location of irfanview application
   mask = "jpg,png,gif"                                   'files to process inside folder
   panextn = ".jpg"                                       'file type for panoramas

   If wscript.arguments.count = 0 then
    msgbox "No folder selected" : wscript.quit
   else
    process = wscript.arguments(0)
   end if

   Appcall = chr(34) & Irfanview & chr(34) & " "  
   panout= process & "\panoramas"
   if fso.FolderExists(panout) = false then fso.CreateFolder(panout)

   Set f = fso.GetFolder(process)
   Set folderlist = f.Files
   Count=1
   For Each item in folderlist
      test= item.name : dot=InstrRev(test,".")
      if dot >1 and len(test)-dot >1 then extn = mid(test,dot+1) else extn = "none"
      if instr(1,mask,extn,1) >0 then
         File(count) = test
         If count=3 then count=0 : pano File(1), File(2), File(3)
         count=count+1
      End If
   Next

   set shell=nothing
   set objFSO=nothing
   WScript.quit

   Sub pano (f1,f2,f3)
     concat = panout & "\" & head(f1) & "_" & head(f2) & "_" & head(f3) & panextn
     filestring = "1," & f1 & "," & f2 & "," & f3               ' horizontal=1 , vertical=2
     shell.Run Appcall & "/panorama=("& filestring & ") /convert=" & concat ,2 ,true
   ' wscript.echo concat
   End sub

   Function head(name)
    head=left(name, instr(name, ".")-1)
    name= process & "\" & name
   End function
   ```
4. This is a *.bat file that i'm using to print the image.. 
   Works terrific.

   @echo off

   ```
   setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

   rem ************
   rem * Settings *
   rem ************

   rem Path to Irfan view
   rem If IrfanView is installed in the common program files folder this part
   rem should be usable.
   rem If you have installed IrfanView elsewhere, i.e. in D:\Tools\IV then
   rem just delete these lines and uncomment and modify the set iview line.
   if /i "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" equ "AMD64" (
    if exist "C:\ProgramFiles\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" (
     rem Path to 64 Bit IrfanView on x64 Windows
     set iview="C:\ProgramFiles\IrfanView\i_view64.exe"
    ) else (
     rem Path to 32 Bit IrfanView on x64 Windows
     set iview="C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"
    )
   ) else (
    rem Path to 32 Bit IrfanView on x86 Windows
    set iview="C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"
   )
   rem set iview="D:\tools\i_view32.exe"
   if not exist %iview% goto noIview

   rem Configure variables
   rem Delay in seconds
   set delay=10

   rem Directory to be scanned
   set scandir=D:\Photo

   rem Directory to move pictures after printing
   set printeddir=D:\Photo\Photo Printer

   rem File types (seperate with colon)
   set filetypes=.jpg:.jpeg

   rem Text file to keep file names of printed files
   set printed="%scandir%\PrintedWithIrfanView.txt"

   rem Use default printer
   set print=/print="HP"
   rem Or set a special printer, just replace the printer name and remove the "rem"
   rem set print=/print="My special printer"


   rem Additional tools
   set choice="%SystemRoot%\system32\choice.exe"
   if not exist %choice% goto nochoice
   set find="%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe"
   if not exist %find% goto nofind

   rem Check if the directory containig the pictures exists
   if not exist "%scandir%" goto noscandir

   rem Check if a directory name for printed images is set and the directory exists 
   if "%printeddir%" neq "" (
    if not exist "%printeddir%" (
     mkdir "%printeddir%"
     if not exist "%printeddir%" goto noprinteddir
    )
   )

   rem Change to the input directory
   pushd "%scandir%"

   echo Scanning directory
   echo  %scandir%
   echo for new pictures and print them.
   echo.
   rem Do the loop
   :loop
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do call :check "%%~fa" "%%~xa"

   rem Ask for exit or continue scanning
   %choice% /T %delay% /C XC /D C /M "X for exit, C for immediate checking."
   if errorlevel 2 goto loop

   rem After finishing go to the end
   popd
   goto end

   rem Check file
   :check
   echo %time% Checking...
   rem Check the file type
   echo %filetypes% | %find% /i "%~2" >nul
   if errorlevel 1 goto :eof
   rem File type ok

   if "%printeddir%" neq "" goto check2

   rem If the text file does not exist, print
   if not exist %printed% call :print %1

   rem Check if the file name is already in the text file
   type %printed% | %find% /i %1 >nul
   if errorlevel 1 call :print %1
   goto :eof

   rem The file have to be moved to the printed directory so there is no need for creating
   rem and checking the "printed" text file.
   :check2
   call :print %1
   move %1 "%printeddir%"
   goto :eof

   :print
   rem Print the picture
   echo Printing %1
   start "IrfanView" /wait %iview% %1 %print% /ini="%scandir%"

   if "%printeddir%" equ "" goto :eof
   rem Appending file name
   (echo %~1)>>%printed%
   goto :eof

   :noscandir
   echo %scandir% not found.
   goto end

   :noprinteddir
   echo %printeddir% not found and cannot be created.
   goto end

   rem IrfanView could not be found.
   :noiview
   echo IrfanView not found in the given path:
   echo   %iview%
   goto end

   rem choice could not be found.
   :nochoice
   echo choice.exe not found in the given path:
   echo   %choice%
   goto end

   rem find could not be found.
   :nofind
   echo find.exe not found in the given path:
   echo   %find%
   goto end

   rem End of the script
   :end
   endlocal
   ```

Comment: There is a lot of code here. Several places say that it is working. What part is not working or missing? I find it difficult to believe it is working well unless you have removed the space characters from "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" directory names.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code

Comment: If you want a cmd script (.bat file) to continuously watch for four (4) files to be found in a directory, it is going to require a program instance on your Windows program bar as long as it is looking. Is that really what you want?